# How to make a character vector with known occurences of specific values in order in R

Tags: r, vector, character

I am trying to create a character vector where specific values occur a known amount of times in a specific order.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
n <- c(2, 4, 1)
values <- c("Health", "Politics", "Sociology")
```

What I want to end up with is a vector looking like this:

```
"Health", "Health", "Politics", "Politics", "Politics", "Politics", "Sociology"
```

I suspect this might be a very simple question, however, I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `rep(values, n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `rep` -

```
rep(values, n)
#[1] "Health"  "Health"  "Politics"  "Politics" "Politics" "Politics" "Sociology"
```